# XWPFDocument gives NoClassDefFoundException :org.doc4j.NameSpace

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, xwpf

I have tried to read a docx file from my android application but the following code gives `NoClassDefFoundException :org.doc4j.NameSpace`

```
try{
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile); 
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
}
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The stack trace is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.dom4j.Namespace
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.java:49)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:149)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:136)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:52)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:98)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:199)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:178)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:53)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:71)
```

Please Help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `dom4j.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it.

Comment: In which libs folder? Asr all jars in libs folder added to your classpath?

Comment: How to add to class path in eclipse?

Comment: In your "Run configuration" on tab "classpath" --> "user Entries" --> Add jars.